# Mongodb install failing with Homebrew - SHA1 mismatch

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I am trying to install MongoDB on my Mac OSX 10.6.8. I am using the Homebrew method. Homebrew appears to be correctly installed - running brew update generates the message 'Already up-to-date'. But when I run brew install mongodb I get this message:

```
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 72152f9bec94aaaacb16d0b17511b0862d38ac21
Actual: 631676c22f98f9b7b87808130a4c1a99d7bf74b1
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mongodb--patch-72152f9bec94aaaacb16d0b17511b0862d38ac21.patch
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

If I remove that file, re-update brew, try to re-install mongodb, I get exactly the same result. 
other action(s) taken - I ran sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports per instructions I was reading which I am not sure now where that came from, but it was that Homebrew and macports can interfere with each other.

If some understands what this problem is, and how to solve I would be grateful for the help.

When answering it would be wise to assume I am a newbie for this task.

Comment: I think my problem is my xCode is out of date. I will update that, and retry.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'll let you know if I find a fix.

Comment: Made a github issue for it: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27754

Comment: Okay so I updated xCode - which was needed but not the problem. The above github issue for Homebrew was the answer. Thank you Shadow.